# Nextjs 14 error Module not found: Can't resolve './${bgUrl}'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx, next.js13

I'm getting the following error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve './${bgUrl}'

when I'm simply trying to set an image url via react state like so

```js
'use client'
    
import { useState } from 'react'
    
export default function HomePage(){
    const [bgUrl, setBgUrl] = useState('/images/bg.jpg')

    return (
        <div 
            className={`relative h-full w-full overflow-hidden bg-no-repeat bg-cover bg-center`}
            style={{backgroundImage:`url(${bgUrl})`}}
        >
    )
}
```

any idea why?

Comment: `/images/bg.jpg` is this path correct? (images folder must be in public folder right?)

Comment: @YashashriPawar it is. switching the state variable for the hard coded url is the first thing I tried, of course. and it works that way so the url is correct, yeah